# Baud rate in PIC18F4550

Tags: pic, baud-rate

for computing the baud rate for PIC18F4550, the following equation is used:
`Baud = F_OSC/(4 * (SSPADD + 1))`  ---------- eq.1

according to the data sheet:
`SSPADD = 10` for 400k Baud at 20Mhz Fosc.

But by substituting the parameters into equation (1), the SSPADD will equal 11.5 
so how is `SSPADD = 10`?

Comment: If this equation is correct you're right that 11 is closer to 400k...

Answer (score 0):

Give this utility a shot. I came across it across it on microchip's forums while trying to get my dsPIC33f's uart working and it made my life much easier.

http://www.micromagicsystems.com/#/pic-baud/4523812801

Hopefully it will work with the particular chip you are using (it looks like it supports *16, *17, *18 and *24 PICs, in addition to the dsPICs).